# How can I embed a file as an attachment to a pdf file via php?

Tags: php, pdf, zugferd

I want to embed generated [ZUGFeRD Data](https://github.com/easybill/zugferd-php) to a PDF file (generated via [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)). I think it's not possible using FPDF directly. So the PDF file must be opened after it's written. How can I do this without command line tools? The site is hosted on a server, where I cannot install any command line tools.

ZUGFeRD is literally a XML file (german standard for exchange of invoices to make it easier for computers to read the document).

[image: This is an example, how it should look like]

Comment: _"I think it's not possible using FPDF directly."_ -why, is what you need here more than a simple attachment? http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script95.php

Comment: It's just a simple attachment, yes. I followed the "Manual" link on fpdf.org - I did not mention a function there. I'll try the extension you've linked tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Did you make it work using the FPDF extension script95? @SuperNova

Comment: I never got it to work. My tax accountant told me, that it would not save any money for me, so I skipped after this information.

Answer (score 0):

When talking of the "simple attachment" you speak about PDF/A-3 file attachments, all of which require custom PDF/A Schema Extensions. If you have at least a PDF/A-1 compliant file you can use @GPs library https://packagist.org/packages/atgp/factur-x to convert to PDF/A-3 and attach the XML.